# Is there an R function which can replace a loop which makes use of several columns of several dataframes?

Tags: r, loops, distance

The goal is to calculate the distance between all traffic counters along the highway and all the gas stations in Belgium. So I need the distance from every counter to every station. In the dataframe Belgium you can find the longitudinal and lateral distances of counters, in the dataframe Stations you can find those of the gas stations.

For now I used a for loop, this works fine for small dataframes but is very slow for huge ones, which is a characteristic of loops.

`Stations1<-Stations[,c("lon","lat")]
    names(Stations1)<-NULL
    BELGIUM1<-BELGIUM[,c("lon","lat")]
    names(BELGIUM1)<-NULL`

```
distancesToStation <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow = nrow(Stations),ncol = nrow(BELGIUM)))

     for (i in 1:nrow(BELGIUM)) {
     for (j in 1:nrow(Stations)){
          distancesToStation[j,i] = gmapsdistance(origin = 
                 paste0(Stations1[j,1],"+",Stations1[j,2]),
                 destination =  
                           paste0(BELGIUM1[i,1],"+",BELGIUM1[i,2]),
                 mode = "driving",key = "X")[[2]]/1000
```

}}

```
save(distancesToStation, file = 'DistanceMatrix.Rdata')
```

This code works perfect for small dataframes, is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: probably you need `expand.grid` between your two tables then use `mapply`

Comment: I need the distance from each counter to each station, not the distance between the counters itself, so does this also work with expand.grid?

Comment: it will be easier with `merge` as in Cole's answer below, `expand.grid` works on vectors not tables (sorry)

Comment: Hi Amon. Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make a reproducible example. Since we don't have access to your data, it's really tough to help you. You need to try to make your data and code as accessible as possible. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This first generates all of the combos with a cross join `merge(..., ..., by = NULL)` and then just uses the vectorized approach for `gmapsdistance`. Note, I don't have an API or anything so that part I couldn't test.

```
BELGIUM <- data.frame(counters = 1:10
                      , lat = runif(10, 10, 20)
                      , lon = runif(10, 40, 50))

STATIONS <- data.frame(station = LETTERS[1:10]
                       , lat = runif(10, 10, 20)
                       , lon = runif(10, 40, 50))

All_Combos <- merge(BELGIUM, STATIONS, by = NULL)

All_Combos$distancesToStation = gmapsdistance(origin = paste0(All_Combos$lat.y,"+",All_Combos$lon.y),
                                   destination =  paste0(All_Combos$lat.x,"+",All_Combos$lat.x),
                                   mode = "driving",key = "X")[[2]]/1000
```